# How do I carry over a selected filter from one php file to a new window/php file?

Tags: php, html

I have a select statement in one php file.  Once users select their filter option, there is another button they can click that will take them to a new page.  This new page is another php file.  I would like the filter selected from the first php file to carry over to the 2nd php file.
Here is the select statement:

```
<form name="CapYTimeForMajorInitiatives" method="post">
<b>Select Date Range: </b>  <select id="daterange" name="daterange" required>
                                                  <option <?php if ($daterange == '' ) echo "selected"; ?> value='' >Select a date range</option>
                                                  <option <?php if ($daterange == 'currentqtr' ) echo "selected"; ?> value='currentqtr' >Current Quarter</option>                                               
                                                  <option <?php if ($daterange == '30days' ) echo "selected"; ?> value='30days' >Last 30 Days</option>
                                                  <option <?php if ($daterange == 'ytd' ) echo "selected"; ?> value='ytd' >Year to Date</option> 
                                                  </select>

</br>
</br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

And here is the script for the new window:

```
<p>Click the button for associate breakdown.</p>
<button onclick="mySQL1()">Associate Breakdown</button>
    <script>
    function mySQL1() {
      window.open("http://blahblahblah.php");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use session maybe ? or possibly use hidden form input on the 2nd page which passes value from the first page to the third one (if I understand it correctly)

Comment: There might be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do here but in the present scenario, session might be the best option. http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php